# How do I convert a literal string value to date format?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have a literal string which is " 2015-12-08T13:04:51Z " , which I would like to convert to date format to show : December 08, 2015 3:04:51 pm. But every time I try all the solutions available online my app crashes with a bad date format exception . 
How do I get it to display the requiredformat. The current code I am using is :

```
            String mydate = ((Search) searchResult).getmydate();
```

which returns "2015-12-08T13:04:51Z "
I tried this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");  
    try {  
        Date date = format.parse(mydate);  
    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
 result = date;
```

But every single time I do that it crashes. Any ides how to go about it in the UTC time zone in the required format?

Comment: "But every single time I do that it crashes" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: even so I am not able to figure out how to convert the given string to the required date time format? how do I go about it?

Comment: Well, for starters, you edit your question and post the stack trace. How are we supposed to help you with your crash if we do not know what the crash *is*?

Comment: sure.also, is there a generic way to convert a literal string like " 2015-12-08T13:04:51Z " to something like " December 08, 2015 3:04:51 pm"

Comment: Parse the original string into a `Date`, then format the `Date` into the desired string. Whether you use `SimpleDateFormat` or a library is up to you.

Comment: what is the simpledateformat for something to look like "december 6, 2015 10:55am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method

```
public static String readDate(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    Date d = format.parse(dateStr);

    format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

    return format.format(d);
}
```

if it has an error try to trim your `mydate` variable.